# Subset a dataframe that contains strings with special characters like "/"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
  ID   Name                               Measurement            
  111  XTANACDA55_156_T110\L_PM3\3 N13    Length
  112  AADARU_16\L_PM3\4 N13              Height
  113  XTANACDA55_156_T110\L_PM3\3 N13    Length
  114  AADARU_16\L_PM3\4 N13              Height
```

I am trying to subset this

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  filter(Name == "XTANACDA55_156_T110\L_PM3\3 N13" & Measurement == "Length")
```

It throws an error saying "**'\L' is an unrecognized escape in character string**"

How can I subset this without converting the string? Any help would be appreciated.

My **desired Output** is

```
  ID   Name                               Measurement            
  111  XTANACDA55_156_T110\L_PM3\3 N13    Length
  113  XTANACDA55_156_T110\L_PM3\3 N13    Length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double each backslash (`\`) like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(Name == "XTANACDA55_156_T110\\L_PM3\\3 N13" & Measurement == "Length")
```

The backslash in a string is an escape character. If you want to be interpreted literally you need to escape it with another.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Schifini.